# Sending js multiple data via Ajax to email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html-email

I need to send multiple data as array and form input values to email via Ajax. What's wrong with this code? The array doesn't return to email, guess something's wrong in php file
***html:

```
<form id="form-order">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="tel" name="phonenumber">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

***js:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {mydata: JSON.stringify(MyObjects)}, 
   url: "index.php",
   success: function(data){
   }
});
    var array = [{count:1,image:"images/1.jpg",name:"Bouquet 1",price:49},{count:5,image:"images/1.jpg",name:"Bouquet 9",price:77}];
            $("#form-order").submit(function() {

                        var order_data = cart;
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST", 
                        url: "../order.php", 
                        data: {form: form_data, 
                        order:JSON.stringify(order_data)},
                        success: function() {                         
                        console.log('OK');
                        });
                });
```

***PHP:

```
$to = "mail@mail.ru";
$message = '
        <html>
            <head> 
            </head>
            <body>
               <p>Name: '.$_POST['first name'].'</p>
               <p>Phone: '.$_POST['phone number'].'</p>
               $someArray;
               $extradata = json_decode($_POST['order'], true);
               foreach ($extradata as $key => $value) {
               $someArray .= "<p>".$value["image"] . ", " . 
               $value["name"] . "</p>";
              </body>
        </html>';
```

Comment: You have to decode the stringified content, because other wise you will not be able to iterate trough the arrays you send to your php script.

Have a look on json_decode() function from php, you will know, what you have to do.

Comment: Show your other form too.

Comment: @rebru Can you have a look, I've added  json_decode() to php. Is it right now?Thanks

Comment: Have a look on the full answer below - but remember, its only a way to go. You are mixing the $message to hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your PHP piece of code, you should better truncate the pieces, for better support to edit it and read it easier, like .... Please notice, this is only a direction to go, its not the working solution.

```
/* Defintions */
$to = "mail@mail.ru";
$extradata = json_decode($_POST['order'],true);

/* HTML Structure */
$head = "
        <html>
            <head> 
            </head>
            <body>
";
$footer = "
            </body>
        </html>';
";

/* Content */
$content = "";
$content .= "<p>Name:".$_POST['first name']."</p>";
$content .= "<p>Name:".$_POST['phone number']."</p>";
foreach($extradata as $key => $value)
{
    $content .= "<p>".$key."=".$value['image']."</p>";
}

$htmlEmail = $head.$content.$footer;
```